# What hardware do I use to detect an electric current going to a lightbulb and tell if it is turning on and off

Tags: programming, hardware

I’m doing a project where you have to detect a lightbulb coming on through the electrical current and was wondering what Hardware and what the program is? Can y’all help? Very much appreciated if y’all do.

Comment: What kind of Arduino will you be using?

Comment: What about a current sensor? The code depends on the sensor. Choose a fitting one and try to interface it with an Arduino. You can always come back with a specific question

Comment: I am using an Arduino uno

Comment: I never thought about a current sensor. Thank you very much

Comment: this part of the title is redundant `and it turning on and off`

Answer (score 2):

A suitable piece of hardware would be a ACS712 Current Sensor which can be used with any Arduino which runs on 5 volts -for instance an Arduino Uno.

You may find [this guide](https://www.electronicshub.org/interfacing-acs712-current-sensor-with-arduino/#A_Brief_Note_on_ACS712_Current_Sensor) useful in writing the program.